# Extract pre-formatted data from a String

Tags: python, string, parsing

I am receiving the following string via an API in Python:

```
{"id":13021,"buys":{"quantity":3494,"unit_price":257},"sells":{"quantity":3187,"unit_price":433}}
```

I can reliably isolate the `"id"` field via `.find`, but the `"buys"` and `"sells"` entries for `"unit_price"` are harder to recover since they don't share unique identifiers. Is my best bet to parse the whole thing with regular expressions, or does Python offer a more straightforward solution to access the required substrings?

Comment: That's [JSON](http://json.org/). Use the Python module [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Thank you! That makes processing it a lot more straightforward. Here I was worried I'd have to parse it all manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data is JSON. Using regexp in this case is overkill. You could convert it to `dict` and work with it like

```
import json
instr = '{"id":13021,"buys":{"quantity":3494,"unit_price":257},"sells":{"quantity":3187,"unit_price":433}}'

injs = json.loads(instr)

injs["buys"]
Out[62]: {'quantity': 3494, 'unit_price': 257}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> a = instr = '{"id":13021,"buys":{"quantity":3494,"unit_price":257},"sells":{"quantity":3187,"unit_price":433}}'
>>> b=literal_eval(a)
>>> b['sells']
{'unit_price': 433, 'quantity': 3187}
>>>
```